# Simplifying an inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm trying to find equivalent conditions on $x, z, t$ (all positive real numbers) so the following holds:

$$\frac{x^{t}}{z^{t}}-\frac{\log\left(z\right)\left(x^{t}-1\right)}{\log\left(x\right)\left(z^{t}-1\right)}\geq0$$

In particular, the above inequality may be equivalent to $x\geq z$. However, I'm struggling to find a proof/counter-example for this.

Looking at graphs, the equivalence seems true. What's a proof or counter-example for it? If the equivalence is false, how could the inequality be simplified?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Try to show that $\frac{x^t \log x}{x^t-1}$ is an increasing function by derivative method.

Comment: okay yes I've shown that, and the inequality is equivalent to $\frac{x^{t}\log\left(x\right)}{x^{t}-1}\geq\frac{z^{t}\log\left(z\right)}{z^{t}-1}$ so the result follows. I can't mark your comment as an answer, but thanks!

Comment: Ok I’ll convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inequality can be phrased as $$\frac{x^t \log x}{x^t-1}\geq\frac{z^t\log z}{z^t-1}.$$ If you can show that the function $\displaystyle f(y)=\frac{y^t\log y}{y^t-1}$ is an increasing function,(hint: take the derivative and prove that it’s positive for the required domain), then the result follows.